# Why is my embedded Linux unable to detect the sd device?

Tags: linux, embedded, devices, sd-card, buildroot

I have this ARM9 SAM9G25 embedded System, running a Linux 2.6.39 Kernel and a Busybox. I put the Images (of the bootloaders, and the linux+initramfs) on a SD so that in the end the system is booting from it - this works no problem so far.

Now when I try to get access of the SD card in Linux or Busybox then the problem starts. It's not there no entry in

```
ls /dev
```

about `mmcblk0p1`, `mmcblk0`, `sdb` or anything else related. But with

```
cat /proc/devices
```

in the last line there is

```
179 mmc
```

I guess the 179 is the major number, so I tried to add it to the device_table,  so that buildroot generates the `mmcblk0p1` for the next image

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 b 755 0 0 179 0 - - -
```

> (that's respectively: 'name' 'type' 'mode' 'uid' 'gid' 'major' 'minor' 'start' 'inc' 'count')

but nothing changed again the drivers are selected in Linux menuconfig.

Does anyone know why I can't even see the SD Card/Device?